# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (-1 ... -1) starts before 0, in AccessibilityNodeInfo.java at AccessibilityNodeInfo.replaceClickableSpan

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback, spannablestringbuilder

Lately we've been experiencing a lot of crashes in our application due to IndexOutOfBoundsException being thrown by Android internally.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (-1 ... -1) starts before 0
       at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1331)
       at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:685)
       at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:677)
       at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.replaceClickableSpan(AccessibilityNodeInfo.java:2925)
       at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.setText(AccessibilityNodeInfo.java:2889)
       at android.widget.TextView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(TextView.java:12028)
       at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:8925)
       at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(View.java:8884)
       at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:8869)
       at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.populateAccessibilityNodeInfoForView(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:396)
       at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.findAccessibilityNodeInfoByAccessibilityIdUiThread(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:358)
       at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.access$500(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:74)
       at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1547)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8302)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1037)
```

have find answer in stack overflow [Android SpannableStringBuilder IndexOutOfBoundsException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70113706/android-spannablestringbuilder-indexoutofboundsexception#) but not find Any answer

I have try to reproduce but no luck, have one try that if device has talkback on and app is crash but not sure that all user has activate this talkback

I would be happy to hear any ideas what the problem could be :)

Answer (score 2):

Considering whether you have used `SpannableString` and `NoCopySpan` in your project. This error occurs when users enable the accessibility feature. You can trace the source code from the provided clues below.

`android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo#setText`
`android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo#replaceClickableSpan`

[SpannableStringBuilder](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.java;l=85?q=SpannableStringBuilder)

[image]

However, if you don't use `NoCopySpan`, it may lead to memory leaks. My personal solution is to abandon their usage and refactor the code in that part using alternative components.

[If you understand Chinese, you can refer to a post for more detailed information.](https://blog.csdn.net/oneokrock/article/details/117036656)